# Raspberry pi emulator for windows

Tags: raspbian, emulation, qemu, raspbian-stretch

i found a web article for configure raspberry pi emulator for windows, but i couldn't able to bookmark the page. But i have these tools and any one can tell me how to configure raspberry pi emulator using these ?
[image]

Comment: Should be possible with qemu. 

Not sure whether it helps: I setup my Linux box with qemu to emulate a Raspi successfully and documented the steps for Linux on https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/en/raspberry/310-how-to-emulate-raspberry-pi-on-kvm-2

Comment: Thanx man its very helpfull